# Remainder of polynomial division.

Tags: polynomials

Remainder of dividing a polynomial $P(x),$ $ \left (\deg{P(x)\geqslant2}  \right ) $ with $(x-1)$ is $1$ while remainder of dividing the same polyinomial with $(x+1)$ is $-1$. Find the remainder of dividing $P(x)$ with $(x^{2}-1)$.

In short:

$P(x)=(x-1)Q_{1}(x)+1$
$P(x)=(x+1)Q_{2}(x)-1$

$P(x)=\underbrace{(x-1)(x+1)}Q_{3}(x)+A, \; A=?$
$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;=(x^2-1)$

I've written like four pages of manipulation with what's given and either came to where I had begun, or had got nothing useful. 
I also tried putting roots of binomials instead of x but then I get $P(1)=1=A \wedge P(-1)=-1=A$ which confuses me even more.

Hints on what to do?

Comment: The ermainder has the form $Ax+B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT : You should have
$$P(x)=(x-1)(x+1)Q_3(x)+\color{red}{ax+b}.$$
Now use 
$$P(1)=1$$
and
$$P(-1)=-1.$$

Comment: Could you please explain why (ax+b) ?

Comment: Because the degree of $x^2-1$ is $2$.

Comment: So, if I had a polynomial of the degree 3 I would put $ax^2+bx+c$ ?

Comment: @lemniscate: Yes, exactly.